# is it possible to find float that not fit to %.6g

Tags: c, floating-point, precision

Let's suppose that we have always the same C locale.

Is it possible to find such float `value` that in code bellow
`restored_x != value`

```
float x = value;
char s[32];
sprintf(s, "%.6g", x);//do not use snprintf for simplicity
float restored_x = 0.;
sscanf(s, "%g", &restored_x);
```

In other words I find out code that uses `%.6g` for serialisation,
and as I know decimal representation of binary float is not exactly 6 digits  after "dot", it may be 7 or more.
But I can not find such number (value != restored_x) is it exists?

I don't take into consideration NaN and +-Inf and so on special case,
because of there is asserts that verify input in function that uses `%.6g` for serialisation.

Comment: Like ... any irrational number? Or even something like `1/3`? But you are limited with the `float` representation itself, which is limiting to ~7 decimals.

Comment: https://ideone.com/WqJ2uJ

Comment: Thanks, really `%.6g` is bad, while `%.8g` is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `x = 0.0001220703052240423858165740966796875f`, `restored_x` does not equal `x`. Even if the `%.6g` is changed to `.8g`, `restored_x` will not equal `x`; it will be 0.0001220703125.

(This assumes the C implementation uses IEEE-754 binary32 for `float` and correct rounding with round-to-nearest ties-to-even, none of which is required by the C standard.)

64,452,836 of the floating-point values (about 1.5% of the finite values) require nine digits to survive a round-trip binary-decimal-binary conversion.

Answer (score 2):

6 (`FLT_DIG`) is the max number of decimal digits that can be round-tripped from decimal, to `float`, and back to decimal without loss. It is **not** sufficient to distinguish `float` values which are close but not equal; there exist unequal `float` values that will print identically with `%.6g`. You need `FLT_DECIMAL_DIG` (9) digits to safely round-trip a `float` through a decimal string in the worst case, and far more to represent the value *exactly* in decimal.

Comment: `%a` exists to do string transfers of floating point numbers without loss of precision.